# How do you add a pause using the time library in python?

Tags: python, time, libraries

My current program uses the average definitions and prints and inputs; however, how do I use the time library? Do I have to `import time`? 
My program includes a lot of print statements in one particular definition; therefore, I want to add a pause of like 2 seconds each to separate every other print statements as it currently looks too automatic, so how would I go about doing this? 
Also, do I have to continue writing `import time`every time I want to use it? (so every couple print statements)

Many thanks!!

Comment: Would I add them on separate lines, do I need to keep writing import time each time I want to use it, and lastly, do I need to add a colon after 'import time'? @DeliriousSyntax

Comment: Yes `import time` and use `time.sleep` and pass a pause value in seconds.

Comment: So sorry that I accidentally deleted your comment - Please could you re add it as it was a fault on my half. @DeliriousSyntax

Comment: @PaulRooney Would I need to add the line 'import time' every time that I want to use it (every 3 print statements) and do I need a colon after 'import time'?

Comment: no just once per file. You only need a semi-colon if you have 2 statements on the same line.

Comment: Thank you sooo much for the help! It was very much appreciated! @PaulRooney